# fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories), How to add git file to repo?

Tags: python, git, github

i am not able to add a file
to git via windows 10 and also it is giving me this error 
for checking the status also

> fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure the remote url exists in the directory where you are trying to add the file.
Run the following command:

```
git remote -v
```

If it still stays `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

`

then it means git is not configured to your code.

```
git init
git remote add origin <HTTPS URL FOR GIT REPO>
```

then you will be able to add the file